# C#: Prioritzing/reorganinizing a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on a problem where I am to provide a list of strings and I need to organize them in a way that returns a list of strings in their proper order. The string array I'm receiving contains steps and the pre requisite step to complete a task.

Example input array:

```
[
"Step A: ",
"Step B: Step A",
"Step C: Step D",
"Step E: Step C", 
"Step D: ",
"Step F: Step A", 
]
```

The array is organized as such that the first string is the primary step and the pre req required is after the colon. If a step does not have a pre req, it will be blank. With the array above the expected output would be:
Step A, Step D, Step B, Step F, Step C, Step E

I'm trying to think of the best way to approach this and what data structure(s) to use. My first thought was to foreach through the array and get the Steps without pre reqs adding them to a list. I would then need to foreach through the input array again.

Comment: How can step D come before step B?

Comment: @Kld - I believe OP is looking for [Topological sort](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+topological+sort).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I apologize for reopening the question while the intention was just to vote to be reopened. I agree that OP is asking for some sort of a  Topologic sort,  but can't see how he will adopt the answers. From the desired results it seems that preparing a simple lookup and emiting it in bread first order will be sufficient. But please close it again if you believe it should be closed. And take my apologies again.

Comment: @IvanStoev reopneing is  fine. Wikipedia link provided on search results gives enough info - OP should be able to comment/clarify question if more help is still needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the expected output, the problem can be solved efficiently by creating a dependency tree using [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.110).aspx) where the key is pre step and the elements are the post steps, and simply emit it in the [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) order:

```
string[] input =
{
    "Step A: ",
    "Step B: Step A",
    "Step C: Step D",
    "Step E: Step C",
    "Step D: ",
    "Step F: Step A",
};

var output = new string[input.Length];
var separator = new[] { ": " };
var postSteps = input
    .Select(s => s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToLookup(tokens => tokens.Length > 1 ? tokens[1] : null, tokens => tokens[0]);
var nextSteps = postSteps[null]; // start with root
for (int pos = 0, count = 0; count < output.Length; nextSteps = postSteps[output[pos++]])
{
    foreach (var step in nextSteps)
        output[count++] = step;
}
```

Comment: This gives me a great direction to take this. Thanks so much @Ivan

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this with a naive approach, I'd say first list the steps without requirements, then list all steps that require the steps already taken, and repeat.

Any remaining steps run in circles or require a step that does not exist.